# How to interpret inverter power value?

Tags: javascript, web-services

I am measuring the power an inverter is currently producing and I display three different icons. If the inverter can produce a maximum of 5.000W, my ranges could look like this: <1.500 -> cloud, <3.500 -> partly cloudy, >=3.500 -> sun.

This approach has one big drawback, as weather, time of the year and time of the day affect the power generation.

Is there a web service that tells me the current weather in my town?
As I know the current date, how could I vary the three ranges in regards to the time of the year?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not display a sun & rays, ranging from grey (desaturated) with downturned face to yellow (saturated & bright) upturned face?

'Sun' correlates quite well with solar power, if that's what you're doing.. use various grey/color & emotional states to convey the sun itself, rather than worrying about peripheral weather (which is not your responsibility).

It's better to accurately indicate/convey one variable, rather than confuse/conflate it with other factors for which you are not responsible, are not under your control, and which you do not have direct knowledge of.

Comment: That's true! I never thought about it that way. Nevertheless, as this project is more or less my learning session, I would like to solve it somehow. Maybe just by displaying the power rate and the current sky condition / time of day...

Answer (score 1):

That is sure possible to get, either by town name, or with coordinates.
You can use this http://worldweatheronline.com/ or this http://wunderground.com/weather/api/

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I included a web service call now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

OK, I would like to share my final solution.

I created several backgrounds for the widget and - according to the current weather condition - I display the one that matches; also if it's night.   ;-)